# IOS Tableview support all screens and Landscape screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, landscape-portrait

I Was create a UIViewControler in storyboard or XIB with autolayout.

When i add UITableView into the view controller it does not support all screens properly even not support to portrait/landscape screens too.

I Have attached a screen of my story board.

[image]

I am a Beginner for iOS , so i dont know hoe to set constraints.

Please Some one suggest a best tutorial to done this or provide a simple sample application.

FYI: I am using Xcode 6.1 and Objective-C

Thank you!

Comment: what kind of output you were expecting and what wrong output it is giving? this info will help us a lot...

Comment: @mohanraj I think This link help you lot http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial, and http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/. Thanks

Comment: @FahimParkar if i set tableview size width 320 and it will show content with width 320 at landscape screen too. but i want to change width and height dynamically, also need to support all devices's screen size.

Comment: You don't want to set the width of the `UITableView`. You want to use constraints to "glue" its edges to certain other aspects. In the scene above, you look like you want to have it take up the full size of the screen. So, you'll want to set up constraints with zero spacing between the `UITableView` and its superview. After selecting the `UITableView`, click the button at the bottom of the screen that looks like a TIE fighter ("|-[]-|")

Comment: Hi @mbm29414 , i have try to set constraints like your suggestion, but its not worked. can u please suggest me  how to set constraints properly?

Comment: Click that button and check each of the 4 constraints you want (top, left, right, bottom). Make sure to click the "Add Constraints" button. That should "pin" the view to all 4 edges.

Comment: Hi @mbm29414 , I have already try to set able view constraints but , it dont work. i have set both of 4 points as 20, but it didn't make any change.

Comment: Did you remove the part where you manually set the width to 320? Are you getting any error messages in the console at runtime?

Comment: I have set tableview width from size inspector as 560 and height 560. and not getting any error, its work fine but from portrait view only show data within 320 width.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're having trouble with adding constraints to a `UIViewController`.

Here is a good [primer on AutoLayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) on Ray Wenderlich's site. It's a good way to get your feet wet with AutoLayout in Interface Builder.

Once you do that, consider reading [this article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-i-dont-use-interface-builder) about why to **not** use Interface Builder. I was finally convinced by this article to go the pure-code route, and I've enjoyed the results.

Anyway, for your particular example, here are some screen shots to add the constraints to your `UITableView`:

1. When you add the `UITableView` to your `UIViewController`, you probably lined it up so that all edges between it and its containing view matched up. In that case, when you click the "TIE Fighter" button (really called the "Pin" button), you should see the following:
   [image]
2. At this point, you simply need to click the 4 "struts" to add those constraints to your `UITableView`. When you do that, they'll turn from light gray to red, as seen here:
   [image]
3. At that point, simply click the "Add 4 Constraints" button to finish the job. Your `UITableView` should now be "pinned" to all 4 edges, causing it to resize automatically during rotation.

Comment: I dont disable "Auto Layout" , after i disable , its work good. and Than you so much mnm29414.

Comment: its work good  after disable "auto layout " from the viewcontroler's File inspector and tank you to every one. especially mbm29414